# How to know the accurate dimensions of an image if the width and height is match_parent?

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-imageview, dpi

Let me explain the following example:

If I had an ImageView that had width and height = (50 x 50)dp, the dimension for the mdpi density (the baseline density as dp=px) would be (50x50)px. Okay, but what if the width and height of the ImageView is match_parent? How can I know the accurate dimension of the image.jpg for the mdpi density? Should I getWidth and getHeight of all the mdpi devices and make like an average of the height and width ? I don't understand what dimension in pixels sould the image have if I am not working with fixed dp but I am working with match_parent.

I would appreciate an example if possible to set the mdpi image pixels.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Giving you a general solution on two scenarios:
let us assume

```
h -> height of the image
w -> width of the image
cw -> container width
ch -> container height
```

if width of the container is the constraining factor
then the formula to calculate the scaled height of the image will be
`hs=h*(cw/w)` , if height of the container is the constraining factor then the formula to calculate the scaled width of the image will be `ws = w*(ch/h)`